# CSS animation of body background-color not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate the background-color of the body but it doesn't work, it changes the color from green to white but I set other colors in between and I don't understand why some examples of doing this work instead.

CSS code:

```
body {
animation: mainscreen 3s linear infinite alternate;
-webkit-animation: mainscreen 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mainscreen {
    0%   {background-color: #00F900} //green
    12.5%  {background-color: #3363FF} //blue
    25%  {background-color: #993399} //purple
    37.5%  {background-color: #FF85E0} //pink
    50% {background-color: #F9E600} //yellow
    62.5% {background-color: #FF9900} //orange
    75% {background-color: #FF1919} //red
    87.5% {background-color: #FDFDFD} //white
    100% {background-color: #000000}
}

@keyframes mainscreen {
    0%   {background-color: #00F900} //green
    12.5%  {background-color: #3363FF} //blue
    25%  {background-color: #993399} //purple
    37.5%  {background-color: #FF85E0} //pink
    50% {background-color: #F9E600} //yellow
    62.5% {background-color: #FF9900} //orange
    75% {background-color: #FF1919} //red
    87.5% {background-color: #FDFDFD} //white
    100% {background-color: #000000}
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L69egL59/1/

Comment: remove the comments in css you use /**/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `//` is not a valid syntax for commenting in CSS, remove them and your code should work fine.

So remove them, or use `/* color here */` to comment out anything in your stylesheet.

```
@keyframes mainscreen {
    0% {
        background-color: #00F900;
    }
    12.5% {
        background-color: #3363FF;
    }
    25% {
        background-color: #993399;
    }
    37.5% {
        background-color: #FF85E0;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #F9E600;
    }
    62.5% {
        background-color: #FF9900;
    }
    75% {
        background-color: #FF1919;
    }
    87.5% {
        background-color: #FDFDFD;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L69egL59/2/)

Make sure you use semi colons after each property name, even if you declare one property per block.

Comment: simple yet effective could have just used a comment space

Comment: @Anonymous.X Answers are not supposed to be posted as comments :)

Comment: I meant this comment when your answer was in the first form (ie. not edited)

Comment: @Anonymous.X doesn't matter even if the solution is a single line, answer should be posted as an answer and not as a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
animation: mainscreen 3s linear infinite alternate;
-webkit-animation: mainscreen 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mainscreen {
0%   {background-color: #00F900} /*green*/
12.5%  {background-color: #3363FF} /*blue*/
25%  {background-color: #993399} /*purple*/
37.5%  {background-color: #FF85E0} /*pink*/
50% {background-color: #F9E600} /*yellow*/
62.5% {background-color: #FF9900} /*orange*/
75% {background-color: #FF1919} /*red*/
87.5% {background-color: #FDFDFD} /*white*/
100% {background-color: #000000}
}


@keyframes mainscreen {
0%   {background-color: #00F900} /*green*/
12.5%  {background-color: #3363FF} /*blue*/
25%  {background-color: #993399} /*purple*/
37.5%  {background-color: #FF85E0} /*pink*/
50% {background-color: #F9E600} /*yellow*/
62.5% {background-color: #FF9900} /*orange*/
75% {background-color: #FF1919} /*red*/
87.5% {background-color: #FDFDFD} /*white*/
100% {background-color: #000000}
}
```

You can comment like this in css`/* your comment */`